# How to use chrome extension filesystem api?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi as example i want to read

```
c:/x.txt
```

as text

and write? is there any example about chrome.fileSystem ?

Notice : I don't want to ask the path of file to user

Answer (score 3):

Already answered at [Chrome Extension HTML Filesystem Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218890/chrome-extension-html-filesystem-access), I think. Note that [`chrome.fileSystem`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html) only exists in apps, not extensions.

To just read files, try asking for the [`file:///*`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) [host permission](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions).